# Type-Qualified binding in WinRt?

Tags: winrt-xaml

Is it possible to bind data using [Type-Qualified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx#databinding_s) (see `Single Property, Attached or Otherwise Type-Qualified` section) syntax in WinRT?

What I want to get is to have possibility to bind to an item of my ViewModel which is an interface:

```
public interface IViewModel {
     INewsContainer ItemHost {get;}
}

public interface INewsContainer {
     ObservableCollection<INews> News {get;}
}

class ViewModel: IViewModel, INewsContainer {
     // ....
     public INewsContainer ItemHost { get { return this; } }

     // ...
     ObservableCollection<INews> news;
     ObservableCollection<INews> INewsContainer.News { get { return news; } }
}
```

Normally, in WPF binding like the following one works fine (assuming `DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModel`):

```
    <ListView Grid.Column="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemHost.(vm:INewsContainer.News)}" />
```

But if I try doing so in WinRT it fails with log in Immediate Window:

```
 A first chance exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred (...) Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding.Path'. [Line: 35 Position: 17]
```

"Regular" binding, i.e. `Path=ItemHost.News` doesn't work either. It states that `News` property cannot be found in an instance of class ViewModel.

**Workaround**
[This](http://shishkin.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/binding-explicit-interface-in-silverlight-and-wp7/) workaround works fine but I really hate having a converter over here :(

Comment: I couldn't get the workaround to work. `target.GetType().GetInterfaces()` wouldn't compile, and I gave up after chasing that down one more step. I used  Jerry Nixon's workaround, below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you need to implement the interface both explicitly and implicitly.

Like this:

```
public interface IViewModel
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        (this as IViewModel).Name = "Jerry";
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (this as IViewModel).Name; }
        set { (this as IViewModel).Name = value; }
    }
    string IViewModel.Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this

```
<Grid Background="Black">

    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

</Grid>
```

Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Best of luck.